# How to call a function in another component with props using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a file called map.js which has the map and markers

```
{Towers.TowerList.map((tower) => (
<Marker key={tower.id}
        position={tower.coords}

        onClick={() => {
          Drawgraph(tower); //Doubtful
          setTower(tower)
        }
        } />
```

The `setTower()` comes from a React hook.

I want to plot a chartjs graph when a particular marker is clicked. But chart is to be made in `D.js`, while the information for clicked graph is in this one. I wanted so that Drawgraph() could determeine which dataset to use, make a chart and take the chart to `D.js` (where chart is to be displayed). This is what `D.js` looks like :

```
//somewhere in D.js
<div className="chart-wrapper">
       <DrawGraph /> //Doubtful
</div>
```

How to go about this situation?

Comment: Same as data you can pass functions also as props.

Comment: @DananjayaAriyasena will it be possible to share a code snippet for doing the same in this case? I did try but failed ;_;

Answer (score 1):

In react you can use props to pass data from one component to its child component. 
If the `<DrawGraph />` Is not a child component, you can use state management libraries like `redux` or the built-in Context API.